# Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io/node_modules/redis'

Tags: django, node.js

Just starting out with node and I'm getting this error. I am on Ubuntu 12.04 and I have globally installed nodejs, redis and socketio as instructed by http://maxburstein.com/blog/realtime-django-using-nodejs-and-socketio/

When I execute the chat.js by typing node chat.js I get

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io/node_modules/redis'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: did you start the `redis-server` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because your Redis server isn't running.Type `redis-cli` on ubuntu console and see if you connect to the server. If you are not connected to the server try following command,

starting redis,

```
sudo service redis-server start
```

Comment: What if Redis is started. What else would you check?

Comment: @ericso Try using: require('redis') instead. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24976111/1493365