# Cannot find module 'socket.io/node_modules/redis'

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

When trying to do

```
var redis = require('socket.io/node_modules/redis');
```

I get the error "Cannot find module 'socket.io/node_modules/redis" and I can't figure out why. I am running windows and ran "npm install socket.io"

It seems like the same issue here: [Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io/node_modules/redis'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350945/error-cannot-find-module-socket-io-node-modules-redis) but the redis server is up and running.

In my "socket.io/node_modules" folder I don't see anything Redis related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [socket.io](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/9c80317574e5aa042fa3ddacf7513a11cb212e65/package.json#L21-L28) package.json doesn't show a dependency on redis:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "engine.io": "Automattic/engine.io#15afd3",
    "socket.io-parser": "2.2.1",
    "socket.io-client": "Automattic/socket.io-client#05c9632",
    "socket.io-adapter": "0.2.0",
    "has-binary-data": "0.1.3",
    "debug": "0.7.4"
  }
```

Either way, theres no need to directly depend on another library's dependencies. If you need to use `redis` in your code, you can install redis and add it to your `package.json` using:

```
npm install redis --save
```

and require like:

```
var redis = require('redis');
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're using Socket.IO 1.0. Since 1.0 there is no more `redis` dependency. You can follow @go-oleg's recommendation and install `redis` package on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Rather run

**npm install socket.io-redis --save**

This will install this npm package. I used this and it worked.